# My c# http server does not work with aspx pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, server, mime-types

I created a http server using C# and I took the idea from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/452052/Build-Your-Own-Web-Server)

It works with html pages. I tried to add aspx mime-type like this "text/aspx"
but it doesn't work, it's still opened like a text file!

Any ideas?

Comment: I would like to recommend you to read about ASP firstly. I mean it's schemes, how it works, what it does.

Comment: Your server must do special magic to run asp, for simpler CGI-like frameworks like PHP your server simply calls executable and returns standard output of that executable to the browser. With ASP which is tightly integrated with IIS you need to hook in proper place like firing HttpModule/HttpHandler and provided all data needed by framework

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have only implemented static resource handling for your web server. However, for ASP(X) (or any other dynamic content) to work as expected, you need a complex pipeline which loads the file, compiles it, runs the code in the right context, and returns the result (and that is a *very* simplified explanation).

In general, it's no a wise idea to implement your own server stack. You'll very likely end up with a vulnerable and badly performing piece of software. Just use an existing web server (or maybe even just Cassini if you really want to see the internals working).

Comment: Depending on what you try to do it's not a bad idea, it's de right way, per example serving a REST service, using IIS for that is just an overkill, but using an httplistener is more than enough, just take a look at ServiceStack, or think about a little program serving a web interface, you can't force the user to install IIS...

Comment: okay I  think it's a long way and i will face so much problems with this can I use another program server that provide asp services like IIS express and   allows me to use specific IP to broadcast my website not using 127.0.0.1 or localhost , is there any way to do this ?

Comment: @Gusman, I agree that there are valid use cases for `HttpListener`. However, the question (why does ASPX not run?) and the referenced article (which is building a HTTP server on socket basis, with questionable buffer handling and request parsing) is really not the way to go IMHO.

Comment: @mohammad.pro The UltiDev Web Server may filfill your needs, it's free and may be distributed along your applications: http://ultidev.com/products/UWS-Cassini-Pro/Default.aspx